# Editing strings in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I've made a list of lists from a text block where each list contains all the words in a line as a separate element, like this:

```
listoflists = [['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet\n']
               ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis\n']]
```

I want to be able to move through the list of lists, and remove the '\n' from the last element of each list in the list of lists.

This is the script I wrote to try to do this, but it doesn't work because when I return n, it only returns the first element of the first list.

```
def remove_linebreaks(input):
for i in data:
    for n in i:
        if '\n' in n:
            n.strip('\n')
            return n
        else:
            return n
return input
```

Are there any other ways I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over each list and replace the last element with the last element with the `'\n'` stripped.

```
>>> listoflists = [['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet\n'],
               ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis\n']]
>>> for elem in listoflists:
        elem[-1] = elem[-1].strip('\n')


>>> listoflists
[['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'], ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis']]
```

EDIT - Since in the code, you seem to be stripping `\n` from each element you could do

```
>>> [[elem.strip('\n') for elem in lst] for lst in listoflists]
[['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'], ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do `return n.strip('\n')`? You can get rid of the if/else

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension

```
listoflists = [['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet\n'],
               ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis\n']]

[[j.replace("\n","") for j in i] for i in listoflists]
```

Output

```
[['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
 ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listoflists = [['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet\n'],['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis\n']]
for l in listoflists:
    l[-1] = l[-1].replace('\n','')
print listoflists
```

"""
Output:

[['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
 ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'donec', 'iaculis']]

"""

Answer (score 0):

Also, the reason your original code does not work is b/c `n.strip('\n')` does not change the value of `n`. It returns a new string. If you did something like `n=n.strip('\n'); return n`, that would work.